# Recommend Field Validator for Java

Tags: java, validation, field

I find myself again and again implementing a validation system. I was just wondering if somebody could recommend some kind of open source Java library that would have all the necessary methods to validate input field.

Mainly it should have methods to check if a string represents a proper float or integer. Character validation, bound checks etc.

I know I could do everything with try catch blocks, but it just seems to clumsy. Especially when I have a large number of fields to check.

Comment: Improved it. Didn't notice there was this possibility to accept answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest JSR-303 Bean Validation: http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2009/01/getting-started-with-jsr-303-beans.html

Not so advanced but at least you can use regex which is nice.

Answer (score 1):

Guava has a [utility class to check preconditions](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) - but you would still need to have a separate utility class to check that a string is a number etc.